# Run bash script

Tags: ruby, bash

I have this bash script which does something with a given input and passes it to a ruby script:

```
QUERY=$(iconv -f UTF8-MAC <<<'{query}')
/usr/bin/ruby start.rb $QUERY
```

This works fine so far.

I want to run the first line of this script inside a Ruby script, which passes the input to another Ruby script. I'm trying to do this using back-ticks in Ruby but it doesn't work the way I want as the `query` isn't converted. What am I doing wrong here?

```
input = `$(iconv -f UTF8-MAC <<<'{query}')`
Start.go(input)
```

Comment: Please give all of your code and also the output of your program and its expected output.  Your ruby script only has 3 lines and I think the last two are not needed to reproduce the problem so they should be removed.  Don't make us guess what symptoms you are actually seeing, show us.

Comment: You're right, I removed a line from my question and will give more information next time. This problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to interpolate `query`, and string interpolation is allowed in backticks (in addition to double-quoted strings).  The syntax for ruby string interpolation is `#{string_to_interpolate}`.

For example--if you put the following in an .rb. file and run it on a Windows system--then mspaint will launch:

```
var = 'mspaint.exe'
`#{var}`
```

It looks like you're just missing a # character on this line:

```
input = `$(iconv -f UTF8-MAC <<<'#{query}')`
```

Comment: I think I forgot the " parantheses around the interpolation as well. When I use this: input = `$(iconv -f UTF8-MAC <<<'"#{input}"')`, I get the error: `sh: thetextientered: command not found`

Comment: Try without the double quotes around `input` (i.e. `'#{input}'` instead of `'"#{input}"'`.

Comment: But string interpolation does only work with " and not with '?

Comment: String interpolation is allowed in backticks (in addition to double-quoted strings).

Comment: Thanks, that was the part I was missing.